# json.load() function doesn't work- Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

### **JSON load doesn't work for me whenever I run my code,**

---

In this part, I create the code to read the file

```
import json

filename = 'eq_1_day_m1.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

readable_file = 'readable_eq_data.json'
with open(readable_file, 'w') as c:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, c, indent=4
```

Then It gives me so many errors talking about charmap. I think this is because of the maximum capacity. Can I do something about this?

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe "C:/Users/PC/PycharmProjects/Learning/Learning Matplotlib/eq_explore_data.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\Learning\Learning Matplotlib\eq_explore_data.py", line 5, in <module>
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 10292: character maps to <undefined>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have my json file: 'eq_1_day_m1.json' if you are wondering. It's too big for StackOverflow to handle so I didn't add it to the question.

Comment: the content of the file`eq_1_day_m1.json` is missing.

Comment: What is the content of `eq_1_day_m1.json`?

Comment: It's big and I can't send in the whole json code so I didn't add it in the question

Comment: It's not about maximum capacity.  It's because you have non-ASCII characters in your file that are not UTF-8.  You need to figure out what character set to use when you open the file.

Comment: Is anyone going to answer?